# What would the temperature be on Earth without the sun from radio active decay in the Earth?

Tags: geology

I once read that about 50% of the emitted temperature of the Earth is due to radio active decay of uranium and pollonium. Is this true and how would this be done as most of the decay energy are gammarays? Do we really get some heat of these particles?

Comment: That's an interesting question and I wish I had more time to answer it, but you can start by reading this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geothermal_gradient

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape - Yep. It's a duplicate.